# Rails Asset javascript Template Errors

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, templates, assets

Went to bed last night with a full functioning app. I was fed up with webrick's performance and determined to use a different web server for development. I woke up and installed Thin. I instantly received errors. I couldn't figure out what was going on so I uninstalled Thin and went back to Webrick to get some things done. To my surprise the errors were still there!

Here's the error:

```
Started GET "/signin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-28 11:01:28 -0700
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
Compiled application.js  (287ms)  (pid 2928)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 868ms

ActionView::Template::Error (cannot load such file -- ["ok","(function() {\n\n\n\n}).call(this);\n"]

(in E:/[my app's directory]/app/assets/javascripts/admins.js.coffee)):
13:   <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, maximum-scale=1.0">
14:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :debug => Rails.env.development? %>
15:   <%= yield :headercss %>
16:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application", :debug => Rails.env.development? %>
17:   <%= yield :headerjs %>
18:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
19: </head>

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__960238137_43581456'
config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb:5:in `call_with_quiet_assets'

Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (7.0ms)
```

I tried precompiling...I got the same issue. It's puking on my javascript_include_tag...this is driving me crazy. It's looking for the admins.js.coffee file...If I remove it, it will throw an error on the next javascript file in line. I'm totally confused, please help! Somebody help! :D

Comment: I haven't used thin before, but assuming it's a gem, and you added it to your gemfile, it's possible when you ran bundler to install it that either the js runtime you are using or the coffee-rails gem updated, and you're running into an error.

Now, I'm not 100% sure on this, but I think I remember having a bit better stability on windows with ruby 1.9.2 rather than 1.9.1. Could you post your Gemfile, so we can see the details and what runtime you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Wow. I just wasted 5 hours of my life. After going crazy with troubleshooting craziness...in desperation, I started doing weird things....I eventually cut and pasted all my .coffee files out of my assets/javascripts folder and pasted them back and everything worked!!!! and yes I cleared my tmp cache, asset cache and every cache I could think of cache...wtf!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for asking this question and agmcleod for pointing to right direction...
Have started getting this error after trying to upgrade to 3.2, and was trying to figure out the guilty js part for the last few days :)

**execjs and coffee-script-source** has been upgraded recently but not **coffee-script**

```
coffee-rails (3.1.1)
  coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
  railties (~> 3.1.0)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
  coffee-script-source
  execjs
**coffee-script-source (1.2.0)**
**execjs (1.3.0**)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
```

Including these exact versions in gemfile resolved the issue for me, hope it helps you as well.

Cheers